# how many (generic ?) class wordpress have?

Tags: wordpress

what i meant with generic is those class that create by non lead wordpress programmer. i just start reading the source code directly and encounter a class who name filereader and i use it to read stream of file.

Is there any other useful class ? i would like to know so i can utilize it when work on wp ?

I know this is a question spesific for wordpress developer. But i would like the hear any suggestion. anything. Even its a mislead question. ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start here: [Function Reference « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference)